# Whats the best method for storing an offline version of remote data in AS3/Air app for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I am asking here as searching has not come up with a clear solution.

I am developing a mobile app that requires users to submit and share information with other users. The information will be stored in a remote MySQL DB but I was wondering what the best method of storing a cached/offline version of the information would be.

There will be multiple tables in the DB which are all related to the user but I don't think fetching the entire data set each time the user accesses a screen is very optimal so if I could some how store the info locally and only fetch the updated information based on a timestamp I guess that would be better.

I guess the question is should I have a mirror of the DB structure locally on the device and call that first when a screen is loaded, then only fetch new information if the user requests or every 1 min (for example).

User will not be able to submit new information without being connected to the internet so the app will never just store locally and not remotely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just store a set of user data in a local sql db on the device and update it as needed. 
Using sqlite on android is super straight forward.

Comment: Thanks. I have used sqlite in other projects but wasn't 100% sure if this would be the best solution.

Comment: Just make sure that if the data is related to making purchases or anything like that you should not store it on the device in the sql db but only get it when needed at runtime and get rid of it when your done. Anyone with a rooted phone can look inside a local sqldb so the data isnt totally secure.